# Lower bound of $1-x$ involving exponential when $x$ is very small?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, inequality

It is well know that $1-x\le e^{-x}$ for all real $x$. I wonder is there any inequality having the form $1-x\ge e^{-(1+o(1))x}$ when $x=x(n)=o(1)$ and what requirements should be satisfied? Here $x=o(1)$ means $x\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html So we may assume $x$ is very small.

Comment: What does $o (1) $ mean. near which point.

Comment: I revised the question.

Answer (score 5):

You have $$\ln\frac{1}{1-x}=\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\le\frac{x}{1-x}$$ for $x<1$, so $$1-x\ge e^{-\frac{x}{1-x}}.$$ Certainly, $$\frac{x}{1-x}=x\,\left(1+\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=x\,(1+o(1))$$ for $x\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Here is an alternative proof that I think is quite nice, relying on $1 + x \le \exp(x)$: We have $1 - x = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1 - x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1 - x + x}{1 - x}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x}{1 - x}} \ge \frac{1}{e^{\frac{x}{1 - x}}} = e^{-\frac{x}{1 - x}}$

Answer (score 1):

No inequality of that form that holds for $x>1$: 
$$0>1-x\ge e^{-(1+o(1))x}>0.$$
For $a>1/2$, the inequality
$$1-x\ge e^{-x-ax^2}$$
holds in neighbourhood of zero. In fact, by considering the Taylor's expansion at $0$, we get
$$(1-x)-e^{-x-ax^2}=(a-1/2)x^2+(1/6-a)x^3+O(x^4).$$

Comment: Here we may assume $x$ is very closed to 0, i.e, a small enough number.

Comment: I edited my answer with some positive result.

Comment: Thank you. I guess a result of the form $e^{-x-x^2}$ but yours are more general. I wonder how do you find the constraint of $a$?

Comment: I considered the Taylor expansion at 0. Note that for $a\leq 1/2$ the inequality does not hold locally.